# Colours For The Checked List Box

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

I Am Working On A windows c# form.
I have  Checked List Boxes in my form.
And for those checked List Boxes I want To set Predefined Colors.
How can I do It..Is There Any inbuild classes or something to get these predefined colors...please Help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How change the color of SelectedItem in CheckedListBox in WindowsForms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130934/how-change-the-color-of-selecteditem-in-checkedlistbox-in-windowsforms)

Comment: Why does the linked answer from CharithJ not work?  Based on your question, it does.  I would edit your question otherwise.

Comment: I want To set the Predefined Colors for The Checked List Box and Not The selected Item

Answer (score 0):

Rather than repeat the answer, see if [How change the color of SelectedItem in CheckedListBox in WindowsForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2130934/555470) helps you solve your problem.  There is code there that may get you where you need to go although that refers to forecolor and you may need to change the backcolor in your case.

Comment: Sorry This Is Not The Answer That I need