# How to change the color of a paticular checkbox in a CheckedListBox based on a condition?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, conditional-statements, checkedlistbox

I want a checkbox in my checkedlistbox to change color based on a condition in my form.

I tried using this solution:

[How change the color of SelectedItem in CheckedListBox in WindowsForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130934/how-change-the-color-of-selecteditem-in-checkedlistbox-in-windowsforms)

but with the overridden method i can't get the ColoredCheckedListBox class access to the condition to check.

Comment: You'll probably want to add some property on that example `ColoredCheckedListBox` that you set. Since the property is part of the class, you'll be able to check it.

Comment: I added a property which i set when i need to, thanks!